# Creating a file but with an specific name

Tags: bash, scripts, sh

So I have a project which needs to create a list of numbers which then will be sum all together and more, but right now, one of my problems is that that I need to give the user the option to decide what the name of the file will be, so I have a very little knowledge of unix so help would be good

1. usr/bin/bash
2. clear;
3. echo enter name
4. read v
5. cat > v

this is what I have, it's creating the file but as you can already tell, the file name will be v; any thoughts on how I can fix this code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
clear
read -p "enter name" v
echo "Beginning" >$v
```

Comment: Rather than posting a "Thank You" comment, click the checkmark beside the answer to Accept it. Thanks.